I get 401 unauthorized error after successful login in reactjs app with laravel & sanctum
I have created an app with React while using Laravel 10 as back-end (using Sanctum for auth).
When I try to log in on first attempt I get "401: unauthorized" error, but on second attempt it successfully logs in, now if after successful login I logout and again try to login with the same user it works fine.
But if I try a different user the same happens so each user has to try two login attempts in order to be able to successfully log in.
here is my setup on laravel side
auth.php
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
], 

my api routes

Route::post('login', LoginController::class)->name('login');
Route::post('logout', function (Request $request) {
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();
});


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    // admin routes here
});


Kernal.php
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        //
        \App\Http\Middleware\HandleQueryStringParams::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\SwitchLocale::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class . ':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's middleware aliases.
     *
     * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware to routes and groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'precognitive' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}

LoginController.php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     */
    public function __invoke(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validated();

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            // check if user is active
            if ($user->active != true) {
                return alert_error(__('auth.not_activated'), 422);
            }

            // updated signed_in_at field
            $user = User::find($user->id);
            $user->logged_in_at = Carbon::now();
            $user->save();

            $auth = [
                'uuid' => $user->uuid,
                'role' => $user->role_id,
                'name' => $user->name,
            ];

            return result_success(__('auth.auth_success'), $auth);
        } else {
            return alert_error(__('auth.auth_failed'), 422);
        }
    }
}

here is my reactjs setup
axios configuration
// configure axios
export const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
  withXSRFToken: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
});

CsrfCookie component
const HttpCsrfCookie = ({ children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    http
      .get(import.meta.env.VITE_CSRF_COOKIE_URL)
      .then((response) => {
        iLog(response);
        iLog("csrf: done");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        iLog(error.response);
      });
  }, []);

  return children;
};

export default HttpCsrfCookie;

main.js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HttpCsrfCookie>
      <HttpInterceptor>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <App />
          <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </HttpInterceptor>
    </HttpCsrfCookie>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

my user login api function
const userLogin = async (post) => {
  try {
    const response = await http.post("login", post);
    const data = response.data;

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response;
  }
};

login form submit mutaiton (i use react query)
  const { mutate, isPending } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: userLogin,
    onSuccess: ({ data, success }) => {
      if (success) {
        setAuth(true, data);
        navigate("/");
      } else {
        removeAuth();
      }
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (formData) => {
    mutate(formData);
  };

note: the setAuth() function set loggedIn to true and saves some basic user info in local storage.
Any help will be greatly appreciated cause this has been bugging for a week now.
With Regards

If it bugged you for a week and you already know for sure, your code behaves this way, I'd revert the existing addition and re-implement it in a different way as you already know that this way does not work. Sounds like you did it wrong in some part of it, so change that part. Git Bisect can help you identifying the problematic change - in case you use git.

@hakre I tried different ways of doing it but the only way it worked was if I use bearer token but Laravel docs say for SPA we should use cookies based login so that's the problem

@hakre I have done everything according to the Laravel sanctum docs so I don't understand why it's still not working.

Hmm, I have very little clue about that. Personally I'd throw React out and use Livewire if not Htmx, but that's perhaps not a suggestion you'd like to follow at this point in time. Double check all the combinations of routes/groupes/middlewares/aliases?

You need more logging in your application to see what is going on. Log each step of the credential checks to a log fine and see what you find first.
